# Docker stopped accepting connections

Tags: docker

I set up Oracle Database in a Docker container on Ubuntu 18.04 inside Hyper-V on Windows 10 as described [here](https://developernote.com/2019/03/running-oracle-database-in-a-docker-container-on-ubuntu-18-04/).

But when I run the container with the following command:

```
sudo docker run -d -it --rm --name oracle12se -v /home/oracle/oradata12:/opt/oracle/oradata -p 1522:1521 -p 5502:5500 -m 4G oracle/database-se:12.2.0.1
```

I cannot connect to my Oracle Database from another Hyper-V machine and if I check the connection with `telnet` (172.17.66.84 is the IP address of the host machine where Docker is run):

```
telnet 172.17.66.84 1522
```

it does not connect. But if I check port 22 (SSH):

```
telnet 172.17.66.84 22
```

it connects successfully, so it means that the host machine is accessible and its IP address is correct.

To check the Oracle instance is started I run

```
telnet 172.17.66.84 1522
```

or

```
telnet localhost 1522
```

on the host machine (where Docker is run) and it connects successfully.

So the IP address is correct and is accessible, Oracle Instance is run and is listening on port 1522, but I cannot connect to it from a local network.

And what is even more interesting everything worked fine before, but I am out of ideas on what was changed.

What can prevent the connection?

**EDIT1:**

If I run a test script that listens on port 8080 on the host machine, I able to connect from another machine with telnet:

```
telnet 172.17.66.84 8080
```

so it is not Hyper-V or firewall, but looks like it is something related to Docker.

On the host machine:

```
sudo iptables -L -n

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:5500
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:1521

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

ifconfig

docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:98ff:feb3:fbe8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:98:b3:fb:e8  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 88  bytes 2768 (2.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 123  bytes 10688 (10.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.66.84  netmask 255.255.255.240  broadcast 172.17.66.95
        inet6 fe80::980a:fe52:5a8d:1bb7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:15:5d:08:73:28  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 451608  bytes 655072327 (655.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 101353  bytes 8256682 (8.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2853  bytes 157368 (157.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2853  bytes 157368 (157.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethbab7679: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::942e:fff:feee:b333  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 96:2e:0f:ee:b3:33  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 88  bytes 4000 (4.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 166  bytes 15352 (15.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**EDIT2:**

```
sudo iptables -t nat -L -n

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.17.0.2           172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:5500
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.17.0.2           172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:1521

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5502 to:172.17.0.2:5500
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:1522 to:172.17.0.2:1521

sudo docker info

Containers: 1
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 57
Server Version: 18.09.5
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: bb71b10fd8f58240ca47fbb579b9d1028eea7c84
runc version: 2b18fe1d885ee5083ef9f0838fee39b62d653e30
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.15.0-48-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 9.758GiB
Name: tor
ID: TN5P:KKCD:TGRU:HQHV:6SH7:6WTJ:U445:6WYC:D7LS:D6AW:BFVC:2B2U
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Product License: Community Engine

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

Comment: Did You check You linux hosts IPv4 forwarding settings? Did You check output of `itpables -t nat -L -n`? Did You check `docker info` output?

Comment: @EOhm see EDIT2. Does the output look correct?